# Node.js/formidable error is not handled by form.on('error')

Tags: node.js, formidable

I'm using formidable for uploading files. When the upload fails (e.g., when the uploadDir is not writable) the error is not handled by form.on('error'), instead it's an uncaught exception. How do I handle upload errors? This is basically the sample code from fromidable's Readme, with a non-existing uploadDir and an error handler.

```
var formidable = require('formidable'),
    http = require('http'),

    util = require('util');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (req.url == '/upload' && req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
    // parse a file upload
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.uploadDir = '/foo/'; // this does not exist

    form.on('error', function(error) { // I thought this would handle the upload error
      console.log("ERROR " + error);
      return;
    })

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
      res.write('received upload:\n\n');
      res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
    });
    return;
  }

  // show a file upload form
  res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(
    '<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">'+
    '<input type="text" name="title"><br>'+
    '<input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"><br>'+
    '<input type="submit" value="Upload">'+
    '</form>'
  );
}).listen(8000);
```

The error I receive is:

```
events.js:66
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                       ^
Error: ENOENT, open '/foo/9b4121c196dcf3f55be4c8465f949d5b'
```

Comment: This error might _not_ be emitted by the `form` object, but Formidable itself might be doing something else internally without attaching a proper `error` handler where it is needed. Do you get a stack trace? Where does that `open` happen?

Comment: I don't get a stack trace, even error.stack only gives me the above information. open happens, when formidable tries to write the file that I am uploading. What kind of errors are supposed to result in emitting _error_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've seen in [Formidable's `lib/file.js`](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/blob/master/lib/file.js), it tries to open the file as a `fs.WriteStream`, but never attaches an `error` event handler on that stream. When the `WriteStream` fails to open the file, it emits an `error` event, which is not handled in Formidable and throws an error. I'd say this is a bug in Formidable, as the `File` wrapper defined in that file is itself an `EventEmitter`, and could intercept errors on the stream and re-emit them as its own error events for upstream handling.